# Java H2 insert NULL into database

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, h2

currently I am working on a project where I need to store data from a JTable (to be precise from the TableModel) into a H2 database. After some reading and searching, I got my H2 setup running and can connect to the database.

Now I want to iterate over my table (row by row) and insert all the values into my database. This works well, as long as there is no empty cell in the table. The method `table.getValueAt(X,Y)` then returns "null" which makes my SQL query fail because I got hyphens >> **'** << in there around the strings.

How can I make my statement insert **""** into the fields where there is nothing in the JTable, without surrounding every argument (e.g. `"'" + table.getValueAt(i, 4) + "'" + ", "`) in an if clause. I want to be able to load the data later on from the database without having "NULL" in every empty cell.

To be honest I am a total greenhorn to SQL and the only thing I found is something like `isnull(someVariable, 'NULL');` but I am not sure how to exacly use this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.getModel().getRowCount(); i++) {
    String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO TASKS " + "VALUES ("
            + table.getValueAt(i, 0) + ", "
            + table.getValueAt(i, 1) + ", "
            + table.getValueAt(i, 2) + ", "
            + table.getValueAt(i, 3) + ", "
            + "'" + table.getValueAt(i, 4) + "'" + ", "
            + "'" + table.getValueAt(i, 5) + "'" + ", "
            + "'" + table.getValueAt(i, 6) + "'" + ", "
            + "'" + table.getValueAt(i, 7) + "'" + ", "
            + table.getValueAt(i, 8) + ", "
            + "'" + table.getValueAt(i, 9) + "'" + ", "
            + "'" + table.getValueAt(i, 10) + "'" + ", "
            + "'" + table.getValueAt(i, 11) + "'" + ", "
            + table.getValueAt(i, 12)
            + ")";

    state.execute(sqlQuery);
}
```

The exception I get if everything except for the primary key field is empty in the JTable looks like this:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax Fehler in SQL Befehl "INSERT INTO TASKS VALUES (1, ,[*] NULL, NULL, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', NULL, 'null', 'null', 'null', FALSE) "; erwartet "), DEFAULT, NOT, EXISTS, INTERSECTS, SELECT, FROM"
Syntax error in SQL statement "INSERT INTO TASKS VALUES (1, ,[*] NULL, NULL, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', NULL, 'null', 'null', 'null', FALSE) "; expected "), DEFAULT, NOT, EXISTS, INTERSECTS, SELECT, FROM"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO TASKS VALUES (1, , null, null, 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null', null, 'null', 'null', 'null', false)
```

Comment: Please read up on SQL injection and how to use `PreparedStatements`

Comment: Indeed, this should be handled by `PreparedStatement`, not just because of the security issues. Composing SQL queries like this is unreadable, and problematic with `null` and strings that contain single quotes.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will do some research on that.